# Understanding complexity of this python function

Tags: python, big-o

What is the complexity ("big O" notation) of the function f(L), where n is the length of L? I can understand that the running time of the inner function is constant. Therefore is it **O**(n)?

This function is taken from a past test in the course "Introduction to CS Python".

```
def f(L):
    def f_helper(L,i):
        if i:
            return f_helper([L,L], i-1) + f_helper([L,L], i-1)
        return len(L)
    return f_helper(L,3)
```

Comment: Why do you say that the inner function's running time is constant? It takes `L` as an input, so its computation must depend on the size of `L`.

Comment: _" I can understand that the running time of the inner function is constant. Therefore is it bigO(n)?"_ - **O(n)** is not constant time. **n** is proportional to the size of the input.

Comment: @Antimony: The fact that it takes `L` as an input doesn't mean its runtime has to depend on `L`. It doesn't actually read the whole input.

Comment: You need to look into how arrays are done then determine how many operations are required as L increases.

Comment: @user2357112 Fair, but even to compute the length of `L`, it is doing some computation, that does depend on the size of it.

Comment: @Antimony: Python lists carry length metadata around with them. You don't actually have to read the list's elements to determine the length.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh, I did not know that. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, note the base case, which is essentially

```
if i == 0:
    return len(L)
```

where **L** is `[L, L]` from the previous instance.
If **L** is originally a list, tuple, string, ... then `[L, L]` will be a list of length 2, so `len(L)` will be **O**(1).

Next, do you have any object you could pass as **L** for which `[L, L]` would be anything other than a pair of references to the input parameter?  If not, then every instance is merely a pair of calls of **O**(1).

To watch this in action, add a simple tracing statement as you enter the function:

```
print("ENTER", i, L)
```

and watch what you get at each function call.

Is that enough to get you to the answer?

Comment: The inner function's runtime *is* exponential in `i`... but `i` doesn't depend on the input to the outer function, and `i` is never greater than 3.

Answer (score 2):

A quick approach is to instrument the function and run it:

```
def f(L):
    print("Call f({})".format(repr(L)))
    def f_helper(L,i):
        print("{}call f_helper({}, {})".format("  "*(4 - i), repr(L), repr(i)))
        if i:
            res = f_helper([L, L], i-1) + f_helper([L, L], i-1)
            print("{}return {}".format("  "*(4 - i), res))
            return res
        else:
            res = len(L)
            print("{}return {}".format("  "*(4 - i), res))
            return res
    return f_helper(L,3)
```

then

```
>>> f("LLL")

Call f('LLL')
  call f_helper('LLL', 3)
    call f_helper(['LLL', 'LLL'], 2)
      call f_helper([['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], 1)
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
      return 4
      call f_helper([['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], 1)
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
      return 4
    return 8
    call f_helper(['LLL', 'LLL'], 2)
      call f_helper([['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], 1)
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
      return 4
      call f_helper([['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], 1)
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
        call f_helper([[['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']], [['LLL', 'LLL'], ['LLL', 'LLL']]], 0)
        return 2
      return 4
    return 8
  return 16
```

... it should be immediately apparent that the original content of L has no effect on the number of calls made.

Comment: Spoiler alert!  :-)   In short, this is a *very* kludgy way to compute `2^(i+1)`.

Comment: So the complexity will be constant? as in O(1) ?